# No ajax response due to echo array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, implode

I have troubles with a website filter, where I would like to echo information of an array, but doing this the the ajax response will just stop.

This is the array, that is printed with print_r

```
 Array ( 
    [0] => WP_Term Object ( 
    [term_id] => 181  
    [name] => Football 
    [slug] => football 
    [term_group] => 0 
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 181 
    [taxonomy] => activities 
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0 
    [count] => 3 
    [filter] => raw )
```

Here is the code to print it this way:

```
$activities         =   get_the_terms($lesson_id,'activities',true);
print_r ($activities);
```

Now, I only want to print the name and I tried to use implode:

```
echo implode(', ',$activities) ;
```

But, with this line the Ajax response is empty. Same thing happens, when I simply echo one value from Array 0 or when I loop with foreach:

```
echo $activities[0]['name'];
```

The intention is to just print out the string "Football".

Comment: As far as I know you should create this array within the script you call with ajax. Correct me if im wrong. (or you send the array as post data with it)

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your print_r tell that the array contain a collection of WP_Term  objects so you should use

```
 echo $activities[0]->name;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick response!! :)